# How to plot a portion of a 3D surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I restrict the PlotRange such that the gray patch (above z=1) is not in the following plot

```
 z[x_, y_] = 1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y);
Plot3D[{z[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Comment: The gray area is where the function has been clipped to fit the `PlotRange`. You can hide the clipping by using the option `ClippingStyle -> None`

Comment: Thanks, that works nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction`

```
Plot3D[{z[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200,PlotRange -> {0, 1}, RegionFunction -> (#3 < 1 &)]
```

[image]